# pip: ImportError: No module named retrying

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a new environment and install various 3rd party packages on an Ubuntu machine. After having to install condo (for a `matplotlib` installation) and `gdal`, the `pip` function no longer works. Instead I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/imagery/ENVIRONMENTS/Project_1/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.retrying import retry
ImportError: No module named retrying
```

I've called pip both in and outside my environment, and still observe the same issue. Also I've tried a `pip install --upgrade pip` and still retrieve the same Traceback. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I faced similar issue while using virtualenv with Python3. Upgrading pip3 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As a cheap workaround, `export PYTHONPATH=" "` seemed to work for now in order to install other packages, but as soon as I need the gdal package, I have to then set `PYTHONPATH` again.

Answer (score 0):

I  had a similar exception and could manage to repair it.

In my case I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.

I had to re-create the virtualenv. Depending on your choice:

```
virtualenv  .
```

Or

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages .
```